# DataTable list/array issues

Tags: wpf, list, datagrid, wpf-controls

I am trying to figure out the reason behind why the datatable acts differently when assigning a list/array to it.

MainDisplay = An empty dockpanel.

LItem = A class with 2 properties, Id and Data

```
var dgBills = new DataGrid();
dgBills.ItemsSource = new List<ListBillsItem>
{
    new LItem {Id = 5, Data = "Patrik"},
    new LItem {Id = 6, Data = "Thomas"}
};
MainDisplay.Children.Add(dgBills);
```

This produces a datagrid with 3 rows!? One row for Patrick, one for Thomas and one (last) empty row.

If i change it into this, then it produces only 2 rows (as it should)

```
var dgBills = new DataGrid();
dgBills.ItemsSource = new[]
{
    new LItem {Id = 5, Data = "Patrik"},
    new LItem {Id = 6, Data = "Thomas"}
};
MainDisplay.Children.Add(dgBills);
```

Anyone that can explain why it behaves like this? I am getting a list back from the database and i would like it to only display the records that are in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the property `CanUserAddRows="True"` on the datagrid that show you an empty row for the new item, if the underlying collection accepts new items. Put this property to `false` and you should see the same in the two case.

Comment: So easy. The array can not be expanded whereas the list can. Thanks!